# This search bar function was working fine with jsonplaceholder but as soon as I changed it to reqres in it isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I created a template in HTML and with this function I'm cloning some cards into an empty `div`. I get the information out of an API.

At first it was working fine with a different API but then I wanted to add photos to the users so I decided to fetch reqres in. I changed the names and stuff but the `div` just aren't showing.

```js
const userCardContainer = document.querySelector('[data-user-cards-container]')
const userCardTemplate = document.querySelector('[data-user-template]')
const searchInput = document.querySelector('[data-search]')

let users = []
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
  users = data.map(user => {
    const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
    const header = card.querySelector('[data-header]')
    header.textContent = user.last_name
    const body = card.querySelector('[data-body]')
    body.textContent = user.first_name
    userCardContainer.append(card)

    return {
      first_name: user.first_name,
      last_name: user.last_name,
      element: card
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: yes--Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: the error wasnt there before i added a new api

Comment: If you're using a new API then it's likely that the response formats are different, so how you handle the data in `then()` needs to change. Without seeing what the response looks like, we can't help with that

Comment: how would i be able to check that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the `map` function to the return data (an object), but you can only run `map` on an array.

Comment: the same exact code was working fine with a different api

Comment: your other API was probably returning an array. The present one is returning an Object, therefore you cannot use map to see the data

Comment: well, how would you recommend me to do all of this. i just want a picture to be there. should i do 2 function, one fills the names and one fills the pictures with 2 different apis?

Comment: different API = different response. Different responses require different code to process them

Comment: i just looked at the https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 response and it lookes like you want to use `data.data.map` in your `then()` . the reqres api is responding with an object. `object.data` is an array of `objects` with `id`, `email`, `fistname`, `lastname`, `avatar`